# NameError: name 'dot' is not defined

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Tensorflow and Keras.I wrote codes,

```
from keras.layers import *    


match = dot([input_encoded_m, question_encoded], axes=(2, 2))
```

When I run it,

```
match = dot([input_encoded_m, question_encoded], axes=(2, 2))
NameError: name 'dot' is not defined
```

error happens. I think by using `import *` , dot method can be called, but is it wrong? How should I fix this?

Comment: I'm able to import `dot` with `import *`. Have you tried to check it with `keras.layers.Dot`?

Comment: @user2906838 I wrote `from keras.layers import *`,so the error happens.And I wrote ` import keras`,in that time same error happens too.

Comment: (a) don't import * (b) are you sure that `dot` is in the version of keras you have installed?

Answer (score 2):

That's what you want

```
from keras.layers import dot

match = dot([input_encoded_m, question_encoded], axes=(2, 2))
```

And just advice for the future: Don't import via * at all, because it can be misleading to know what's inside, and you can easily make errors by using the same namespaces. Always import full library(script) like using `import xxx` or just import only some function, class etc using `from xxx import xxx`, but never import via *.

Comment: thank you,for your answer.I wrote your codes, so     `from keras.layers import dot
ImportError: cannot import name 'dot'` error happens.What should I do?

Comment: @user9929053 I cannot say what's really can affect this behaviour in your environment. But it's totally supported currently https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/merge.py#L416 . Try updating your keras to the latest version, maybe your current version does not have "keras.layers.dot" class

Answer (score -1):

dot is a function of NumPy, you just call it by numpy.dot(x,y), it will work fine...